# go build error while building sawtooth transaction processor on macos

Tags: go, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to build sawtooth transaction processor on macos. The transaction processor is written in golang. When I do `go build` it throws the following error:

```
go build
# github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-sdk-go/signing
ld: library not found for -lcrypto
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please note `openssl` is already installed

any suggestion/comment would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing below two commands fixed the issue:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: So the problem was you had a local copy of openssl installed, instead of one installed from a package. You should have mentioned that.